# Can the following expression be simplified?

Tags: math, algebra

Can the following expression be simplified?

```
(M == null && C == null) ||
(M != null && C != null && D == C)
```

Mathematically I know this can't be simplified and I checked on WolframAlpha to confirm this, but I was wondering if it might be possible with use of one of the boolean logical operators (&, |, ^), to make that condition shorter. I've tried to think of ways but I'm having a mental block... is this actually possible to shorten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't be shortened.

As Ferdinand Liu observes, your expression is true in two cases:

- Both `M` and `C` are null, or
- Both `M` and `C` are *not* null, and `C` and `D` are equal.

You need to check both `M` and `C` in both conditions, so you can't simplify the expression.

---

Interesting but only slightly-related note:

If you didn't need to check `C` and `D` for equality, then the expression would be

```
(M != null && C != null) || (M == null && C == null)
```

and this *can* be simplified to

```
!((M == null) ^ (C == null))
```

which is true when `M` and `C` have the same "null-ness."

Answer (score 2):

The proposed expression is true under 2 'rules':
Rule#1: both M AND C is null, regardless value of D
Rule#2: (2.a: both M and C is NOT null) AND (2.b: D is equal to C)

Shingetsu's formula will fail in case of D is null (means C == null, that's broke rule#2a)

Failed Test: M=not(null), C=null, D=null

```
(M == null && C == null) || (M != null && D == C)
false && true || true && true    
false || true
true
```

While Jake's original proposed expression will be parsed as:

```
(M == null && C == null) || (M != null && C != null && D == C)
false && true || (true && false && true)
false || false
false
```

J. Bruni's formula will fail in case of either M or C != null (broke condition 1 or 2a)
Failed Test: M=not(null), C=null, D=null

```
((M == null) && (C == null)) || (D == C)
false && true || true
false || true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're assuming that D isn't null then in the second expression you could  leave out the C !== null.

Answer (score 0):

(M == null && C == null) || (M != null && D == C)
This can be done because from what I see in your code, D definitively has a value, so C won't be == to D if it's null.

Comment: In some languages, a null variable returns false, while non-null return true if used alone, so you can also use:  (!M&&!C)||(M&&D==C)

Comment: Why does D definitely have a value? Why can't it be null?

Comment: I'm judging the way D is used in this case. If it IS null, C!=null&&D==C is absolutely useless, so I assume D has a value. If it doesn't it will fail. But if it does have a value, this method does greatly simplify how it looks. (ok not GREATLY)